# trying to populate datatable with data in json format but getting no data available error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

this is the html file which i am trying to execute.But "no data available error" is coming

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tt').DataTable({
            "ajax" : {
            "url" : "D:\bhama\New folder\json_colors.txt",
            "dataSrc" : "cc"
            },
            "columns" : [ 
                         { "data" : "color"}, 
                         { "data" : "category"}, 
                         { "data" : "type" },
                         { "data" : "code"}
                        ]
         });
       });
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>

      <p>The content is written in JSON format, and can easily be converted into a JavaScript object.</p>


      <table id="tt"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>

             <th>color</th>
             <th>category</th>
             <th>type</th>
             <th>code</th>

          </thead>
      </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Even when the url is changed to file name alone then also it is showing "No Data Available"
     json_colors.txt

```
{
"cc":[
   {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code":  "#000"

    },
{
  "color": "white",
  "category": "hue",
"type": "primary",
  "code":  "#FFF"

},
{
  "color": "green",
  "category": "hue",
  "type": "secondary",
  "code": "#0F0"
  }
]
}
```

here i am trying to push json data file into the datatable,but while executing the code i got some error that is "no data available".After that i also tried json_color.json file instead of .txt file but it shows the same error.
So,please help me to solve this error.
 thanks in advance.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.I guess you want to append the color, category and other fields data into data table on URL changes right?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a basic demo of how to append any info or data into Datatable using Ajax. I hope you will get an idea from it. So here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>img</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email id</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Birthdate</th>
                    <th>Zipcode</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

So in my HTML, I assigned 7 columns into data table and my tbody is empty because we need to add data into column dynamically.

Here is my Javascript code.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
         url: 'http://localhost:8080/gettable',
         dataType: 'json',
       contentType:'application/JSON'
        }) 
        .done(function(res){
          console.log('Get Response:',res);
           var table = $('#example').DataTable();
         $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
          $.each(res.docs, function(index, user){

           $.each(user, function(index2, sub_user){

                 $("#example").append($('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
                .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
                .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
                .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
               .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
                .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
                .append($('<td>').append("Color name or anything"))
             ); 
           });
          })
       .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
         console.log('Ajax repsponse:',textStatus);
           alert("nayy")
      }); 
 });
```

So to append anything in the column we need to use .append command which will append the data into your column. I hope it will work for you. Thank you.